# Override CSS text-transform

Tags: overriding, inline, css

I am using the following CSS which transforms all text to uppercase:

```
.taxtabs {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: .8em;
width: inherit;
text-align:center;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Now what I would like to do is to override this CSS and allow certain text to be lowercase.  How would I do that?  Perhaps using some kind of inline CSS?  Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Probably better to create a class that doesn't have any text-transform.

```
.normal {
    text-transform: none;
}

<div class="taxtabs">
... <span class="normal">this text is not uppercase</span> ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a class for whatever elements you don't want capped and put `text-transform: none !important;` in it. I don't know your layout, so I put `!important` for good measure (for example if your element had both `texttabs` and `override` classes).

```css
.override {
    text-transform: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a new class called `lowercase` to selected `.textabs` so you can define something like this:

```css
.textabs.lowercase { text-transform: lowercase; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you wanna to do

if you only want to make some text to be lowercase

you just have to add a new class on it or inherit above css

from

```
<label class="taxtabs">text</label>
```

to

```
<label class="taxtabs lower">text</label>
<style>.taxtabs.lower{text-transform: lowercase;}</style>
```